# How to get list of Entity attached to an Entity without a getter?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, spring-data

I am trying to get a list of Dogs entities that are related to one Kennel entity.

There is a `many to one` relationship between Dogs and Kennels, I.e A Kennel can Have many dogs, but a Dog can only have one Kennel.

KENNEL_ID is a `foreign key` in the DOG table.

The problem is that there is no dogs list attached to the Kennel, so I cannot do something as simple as:

```
List<Dogs> allDogsInOneKennel =    kennel.getAllDogs();
```

However for a Dog Entity I can:

```
dog.getKennel();
```

Is there a way that I can back track to get all the dogs associated with one Kennel?

Kennel Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "KENNEL"
)
public class Kennel {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(
        location = "LOCATION"
    )
    private String location;


    public Kennel() {
    }

    //getters setters

}
```

Comment: could you also add the Dog Entity class definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing it :

1 - just like you declared that @ManyToOne in Dog class, you may want to declare the @OneToMany association in Kennel class :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="kennel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Dog> dogs = new HashSet<>();
```

(mappedBy="***", the *** representing the property name of the @ManyToOne in Dog class).

2 - If you don't want to do the above, you have no other choice than retrieve the list of dogs for a kennel from database using a DAO / Repository layer.

Answer (score 1):

Please find pseudo code and examples for your need.

Kennel 1:N Dog
 One Kennel -> Many Dogs

```
Kennel
 ------

 Kennel_ID:1 
 location:"abc"



 Dog
 ---
 Dog_Id:1
 Dog_Name:DogName1
 Dogken_Ref_Id:1

 Dog_Id:2
 Dog_Name:DogName2
 Dogken_Ref_Id:1







 @Entity
    @Table(name = "KENNEL")
    public class Kennel {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "Kennel_ID")
     private String id;

     @Column(name = "LOCATION")
     private String location;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="Kennel")
     public Set<Dog> getDog();    

    }


@Entity
@Table(name = "Dog")
public class Dog{

   @Id
   @Column(name = "Dog_id")
   private int dogId;

   @Column(name = "Dog_name")
   private String dogName;

   @Column(name = "Dogken_Ref_Id")
   private int kenRefId;


   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="dogken_ref_id", referenceColumnName="Kennel_ID")
   private Kennel kenDetail;

}
```